# How to get top n records from each category in a Python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The data is sorted in descending order on column 'id' in the following dataframe -

```
id   Name     version     copies   price
6    MSFT       10.0        5       100   
6    TSLA       10.0        10      200
6    ORCL       10.0        15      300

5    MSFT       10.0        20      400
5    TSLA       10.0        25      500
5    ORCL       10.0        30      600

4    MSFT       10.0        35      700
4    TSLA       10.0        40      800
4    ORCL       10.0        45      900

3    MSFT       5.0         50      1000 
3    TSLA       5.0         55      1100
3    ORCL       5.0         60      1200

2    MSFT       5.0         65      1300
2    TSLA       5.0         70      1400
2    ORCL       5.0         75      1500

1    MSFT       15.0        80      1600
1    TSLA       15.0        85      1700
1    ORCL       15.0        90      1800
...
```

Based on the input 'n', I would like to filter above data such that, if input is '2', the resulting dataframe should look like -

```
Name     version     copies   price
MSFT       10.0        5       100   
TSLA       10.0        10      200
ORCL       10.0        15      300

MSFT       10.0        20      400
TSLA       10.0        25      500
ORCL       10.0        30      600

MSFT       5.0         50      1000 
TSLA       5.0         55      1100
ORCL       5.0         60      1200

MSFT       5.0         65      1300
TSLA       5.0         70      1400
ORCL       5.0         75      1500

MSFT       15.0        80      1600
TSLA       15.0        85      1700
ORCL       15.0        90      1800
```

Basically, only the top 'n' groups of 'id' for a specific version should be present in the resulting dataframe. If a version has id's < n (e.g. in version 15.0 there is only one group with id = 1), then all the groups of id's should be present.

I tried using `groupy` and `head`, but it didn't work for me. I absolutely have no other clue in getting this to work.

I really appreciate any help with this, thank you.

Comment: What is the rule for subsetting? Your example only seems to drop id=3 when input id=2, which doesn't accord with your explanation.

Comment: Hi ifly6 - With input = 2, the group of names with id = 4 is omitted since version 10.0 has 3 such name groups. Since version 5.0 has just 2 name groups with id=3 and 2, both are included. And since version 15.0 has only one group (which is < n) with id=1, that alone is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `groupby.transform` on the column version, and [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) the column id to have an incremental value (from 0 to ...) for each id per group, then compare to your n and use `loc` with this mask to select the wanted rows.

```
n = 2
print(df.loc[df.groupby('version')['id'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])<n])
    id  Name  version  copies  price
0    6  MSFT     10.0       5    100
1    6  TSLA     10.0      10    200
2    6  ORCL     10.0      15    300
3    5  MSFT     10.0      20    400
4    5  TSLA     10.0      25    500
5    5  ORCL     10.0      30    600
9    3  MSFT      5.0      50   1000
10   3  TSLA      5.0      55   1100
11   3  ORCL      5.0      60   1200
12   2  MSFT      5.0      65   1300
13   2  TSLA      5.0      70   1400
14   2  ORCL      5.0      75   1500
15   1  MSFT     15.0      80   1600
16   1  TSLA     15.0      85   1700
17   1  ORCL     15.0      90   1800
```

Another option is to use `groupby.head` once you `drop_duplicated` to keep unique version-id couples. then use select version-id in a `merge`.

```
df.merge(df[['version','id']].drop_duplicates().groupby('version').head(n))
```

Comment: Thanks Ben.T. This is exactly what i wanted. But when i replaced the column names in the solution above, i am getting a `invalid comparison between dtype=int64 and str` error. The `id` and `version` column types are object when i printed `df.dtypes`. Here is the complete list - `id:object, Name:object, version:object, copies:object, ip:object, price:float64, quantity:float64, labels:float64, is_ok:int64, total:float64`. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Ira so in id you have float-int and str mixed. you can first convert to str with `df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)` then the method. or you can do it in the factorize like `lambda x: pd.factorize(x.astype(str))[0]`. but I assume the second option works with your current mixed type column id

Comment: Hi Ben.T - Thanks for the reply. The error `TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=int64 and str` persists even after changing to `.transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x.astype(str))[0])`. I tried the second solution and it throws `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'` error.